# System.Web.HttpException: The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x800704CD

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, azure, connection-timeout

I looked over all possible answers and I got nothing that could lead me to a solution about that volatile problem.

In the MVC5 web application I work, some users can download an Excel file that is generated when they press a download button. At the moment of writing, the web application do not store the file on the server. So the users need to wait until it has been completed to see it as a successful downloaded file.

I will paste the code below. The problem is that the download method create an

> 500 - Connection Timed out

if it appears to be the first time since a long time this method as not been hit. If a user press the browser back button and do it again, the download time will be very short and the problem will come back many hours later if nobody downloaded their Excel file.

When it does a connection timed out, I got error reports. The first one is :

> System.Web.HttpException: The remote host closed the connection. The
>   error code is 0x800704CD. Generated: Sun, 27 Nov 2016 16:33:58 GMT
>
> System.Web.HttpException (0x800704CD): The remote host closed the
>   connection. The error code is 0x800704CD.    at
>   System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32
>   result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)    at
>   System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()    at
>   System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush, Boolean async)    at
>   System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush()    at
>   System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.Flush()

And the second one is:

> System.Web.HttpException: Server cannot append header after HTTP
>   headers have been sent. Generated: Sun, 27 Nov 2016 16:33:58 GMT
>
> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Server cannot append header
>   after HTTP headers have been sent.    at
>   System.Web.HttpResponse.AppendHeader(String name, String value)    at
>   System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.AppendHeader(String name, String value)
>   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.AddVersionHeader(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state)

Here is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<EmptyResult> Export(ExcelViewModel vModel)
        {
            /*
             * Note:
             * Update the download date to keep track on new entries.
             */
            var fileName = string.Empty;
            var fileStream = await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var e = await _eventService.FindAsync(base.UserLanguageId, int.Parse(vModel.EventId));
                var orders = _orderSKUDiscountService.GetMembershipsByConfirmedOrders(base.AuthenticatedUser.Id, e.Slug, "");

                var lots = _lotService.GetLotByEventWihRecipient(e.Id).ToList();
                var stream = PushDataToExcel(lots, orders, DateTimeUtility.GetTimeFromUtc(e.LatestExcelDownloadDateUtc.Value));

                if (stream != null)
                {
                    e.LatestExcelDownloadDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    if (await _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChangesAsync() > 0)
                    {
                        fileName = Tools.StripAccent(e.Name) + "-rapport";
                        return stream;
                    }
                }

                return new MemoryStream();
            });

            // Write it back to the client
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;  filename={0}.xlsx", fileName));
            Response.OutputStream.Write(fileStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);

            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
            fileStream.Close();

            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

To conclude, this is a MVC5 C# web application, host on Azure with a S0 database. I try to reproduce the problem by putting a long Tread.Sleep before and after the *FindByAsync* and *GetMembershipsByConfirmedOrders* you can see in the code above, which are the requests to the database, but I never got the Connection Timed Out. So I'm a little confused about how to solve it.

Thank you

David

Comment: I think you are confusing request timeouts with database timeouts. And using `Task.Run()` is a big problem. Asp.Net does not like to be told what to do with its  threads. Don't do that, just `await` the async calls.

Comment: @Crowcoder: To make sure I understand correctly, do you mean I should put the code under the comment "write it back to the client"  at the same level as the line return stream; and remove the return statement so as the var fileStream?

Comment: No, I mean just take everything out of your async delegate and don't `Task.Run` anything.

Comment: Why don't you just return a [FileStreamResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult(v=vs.118).aspx) from your action? It would be way easier.